# Removing action bar's shadow

Tags: android

I would like to remove the action bar's shadow and although there are many similar questions, no of the suggestions works for me. I am using 4.3 Api 18 and would like to work for lower and upper versions. Here is my code:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LineRemover</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LineRemover" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

**Update:**
I decide to use a Toolbar as suggested in the comments and now everything works fine.

Comment: Consider using `Toolbar` instead. It's newer and more customizable

Answer (score -1):

try this ,  for 5.0

```
<item name="app:elevation">0dp</item>
```

or try

```
<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: Error:(1621, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:elevation'.

Comment: try second one pls

Comment: There is no a xml. I am using getSupportActionBar(); and actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

Comment: what is your API level and put your code which you add in activity

Comment: I just added a Toolbar in my acitivity's xml as you and Roman Samoylenko suggested. Thank you both!